# Binding/ excluding groups for the McNemar Test

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, mcnemar-test

Our data is like this: Participants could choose one of four parties at baseline and at follow up (Germany has many political parties...). So the table for the raw data looks like this:

[image: Table 1]

For one analysis we want only to look at people *changing* from `A` or from `B` to `C` or to `D`. Our hypothesis is that more people from `A` change to `C` or to `D` than people from `B` change to `C` or `D`. So in this analysis we only look at people who voted for `A` or `B` at baseline and discard the others. Further, we are only interested in changes to `C` or `D`, while changes between `A` and `B` are not relevant to us. Therefore we summarise `C` and `D` to `C or D`. Considering this all what we do with the raw data is the following:

[image: What we do]

As shown above we exclude participants 9-16 because they did not choose `A` or `B` at baseline and participants 2 and 5 are excluded because they changed between `A` and `B`.

The plot of our data supports our hypethesis and the McNemar test is significant. But my question is: Can we use the McNemar Test for the resulting frequency table? I am unsure because we are excluding the factor levels `C` and `D` at baseline and level combinations (`A` to `B` and `B` to `A`).